# Determine number of records updated in update statement using Ormlite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm currently using Ormlite version 4.42 with Android. What I want to do is determine whether Ormlite has the ability to return the number of records updated. Something such as the following:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
count = db.update(COMPANY_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
```

Instead of using a direct SQLiteDatabase connection, I want to leverage Ormlite in my content providers. Just curious as to whether this is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as long as you are using [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) version 4.39 or later.  I now do an additional SQL statement to get the number of changes from the previous one.  From the change-log:

> ANDROID: Finally fixed the number of rows changed for insert/delete/update calls using SQLite CHANGES() pragma.

You could use the `UpdateBuilder` code to make the changes:

```
UpdateBuilder<Company, Integer> updateBuilder = companyDao.updateBuilder();
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("name", newName);
updateBuilder.where().gt("customerCount", 100);
int rowsUpdated = updateBuilder.update();
```

There are also [online docs for `UpdateBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/docs/update-builder).

Comment: @Gray- Is it also possible to retrieve the rowid of the row that was inserted or updated on?

Comment: No, @dionysus.  You can update a number of rows but SQL doesn't supply the updated ids.   FYI: I've added info about the UpdateBuilder to my answer.

Comment: @Gray-Thanks for all your help on this!!